# One of my my bootstrap modals isnt working and I cant figure out why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

So I'm creating an application which can display multiple bootstrap modals, currently I have one modal for signing out and one modal for displaying notifications(this one does not work).

The Bootstrap modal for signing out (**works**):

```
<div class="modal" id="NotificationModal" tabindex="-1" style="display:block;" role="dialog">
               <div class="modal-dialog">
                   <div class="modal-content text-center">
                       <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: rgba(64,0,64,0.95);">
                           <h4 style="color: white;">Are you sure you want to sign out?</h4>
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-modal" @onclick="@CloseNotificationModal">Yes, sign me out!</button>
                           <button type="button" id="SignOutModalClose" class="btn btn-modal" data-dismiss="modal" @onclick="@CloseNotificationModal">No, keep me signed in!</button>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
</div>
```

The bootstrap modal for showing notifications(want this to be full height on the right side) (**does not work**):

```
        <!-- Modal  -->
        <div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Right Sidebar</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- modal-content -->
            </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- modal -->
```

I followed this tutorial: https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa and added the html code into my container (same place as other bootstrap modal) and added the css in my bootstrap.min.css.

Can anyone help me? I'm working on this for 2 days already and cant figure it out.

Niels

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.Check for an unclose div of some modal.

Answer (score 0):

You will need CSS codes to work.

```css
.modal.right .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}


.modal.right .modal-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal.right .modal-body {
  padding: 15px 15px 80px;
}


/*Right*/

.modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
  right: -320px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
}
/* change from fade.in to fade.show */   
.modal.right.fade.show .modal-dialog {
  right: 0;
}


/* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */

.modal-content {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.btn-demo {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-demo:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
   Right Sidebar Modal
  </button>

<!-- Modal  -->
<div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Right Sidebar</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- modal -->
```

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 4.5.0, hence I used `modal.show` instead of `modal.in` in the CSS. The example given is using bootstrap 3.3.5.

Comment: Hi, Im using Syncfusion Blazor. I added the script tags in my _hosts.cshtml and added the lines of css into my bootstrap.min.css and used the modal. Still not working..

Comment: Are u familiair with Blazor Syncfusion? When I copy another tutorial project into my blazor app it does not work aswell. I think im doing wrong but I dont know why? I've tried this code on a complete empty page: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/demos/sidebar/default-functionalities?_ga=2.171109472.1383673467.1591689254-1169174862.1589541388 and it did not work

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with Syncfusion Blazor. Usually, we will have a custom .css file for our custom CSS codes. The custom CSS codes should be placed after the bootstrap css code.